# Process millions of image files and insert each file to mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, insert, pymongo

I have a large collection (~800,000 images, 1TB+ total size) of image files on S3 that I use some Python code to process into a dictionary for insertion to MongoDB. The dictionary contains a buffer that is used by a command like np.frombuffer to reconstruct the image.

I need to process each file and insert it into a MongoDB. So far I've tried multiprocessing the code and while this is effective, it gets slower and slower with each insert - it takes 20 min for 50,000 files but 5 hours for 250,000 files.

I have 2 things I'm unsure about:

1. Why does inserting get so much slower as the number of documents in the database increases, how can I address that? I'm guessing it's because of the more records you have, the more work Mongo has to do to check if the record it's trying to insert already exists but I'm not sure how to mitigate this.
2. What is the best approach to this type of problem? Another idea I had was bulk inserts after writing the processed image files locally.

Code sample below:

```
def process_image(img_file):
   # define MongoClient and collections
   client = MongoClient(...)
   collection = client['collection_name']

   # read image file from s3
   obj = s3.Object(bucket_name='test_bucket', key=img_file)
   im = Image.open(obj.get()['Body'].read()
   
   # create image buffer
   buffer = cv2.imencode(".jpg", im)
   buffer = buffer.flatten().tobytes() # usually around 100,000 bytes

   # dict to be written to mongo
   d = {}
   d['filename'] = img_file
   d['buffer'] = buffer
   
   # insert to mongo
   collection.insert_one(d)

### multiprocessing code

from multiprocessing import Pool

pool = Pool(processes=16)
results = pool.map(process_image, ls_filenames, chunksize=500)
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

`ls_filenames` has around 800k image paths in it.

Answer (score 0):

There's unnecessary overhead creating the MongoClient each time. Create it once and reuse the connection.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I defined the client inside the function because that was the recommendation I saw in the MongoDB docs, unless I'm mistaken - https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/faq.html#using-pymongo-with-multiprocessing